# Error 1054: 'Unknown column ...' while loading manytomany field list data to mysql db in golang

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

#### Summary

Error being displaying

```
Error 1054: Unknown column 'user_user_id' in 'field list'
```

Relevant struct types

```
type User struct {
    Email                 string          `gorm:"size:100;not null;unique" json:"email"`
    Password              string          `gorm:"size:60;not null" json:"password,omitempty"`
    CreatedAt             time.Time       `gorm:"default:current_timestamp()" json:"created_at"`
    UpdatedAt             time.Time       `gorm:"default:current_timestamp()" json:"updated_at"`
    Verified              bool            `gorm:"default:false" json:"verified"`
    AToken                string          `gorm:"size:100;not null;unique" json:"accessToken"`
    RToken                string          `gorm:"size:100;not null;unique" json:"refreshToken"`
    YouAreFollowing       bool            `json:"youAreFollowing"`
    Username              string          `json:"username"`
    Online                bool            `json:"online"`
    NumFollowing          uint64          `json:"numFollowing"`
    NumFollowers          uint64          `json:"numFollowers"`
    LastOnline            time.Time       `gorm:"default:current_timestamp()" json:"lastOnline"`
    UserId                string          `gorm:"primary_key;not null;unique" json:"userid"`
...
}

type UserFollowing struct {
    ID         string  `gorm:"primary_key;not null;unique" json:"id"`
    User       User    `gorm:"foreignKey:ID;references:UserId"`
    Followings []*User `gorm:"many2many:user_relation;foreignKey:ID;joinForeignKey:UserFollowingId;JoinReferences:FollowingId"`
}
```

Relevant variables for the initial db loading

```
var users = []models.User{
    models.User{
        DisplayName: "Ringo Starr",
        Bio:         "...",
        Username:    "q117", 
        UserId: "1", 
        LastOnline: time.Now(), 
        Email: "q@gmail.com", 
        ...,
    },
    models.User{
        DisplayName: "John Lennnon",
        Bio:         "...",
        Username:    "q118", 
        UserId: "2", 
        LastOnline: time.Now(), 
        Email: "q2@gmail.com", 
        ...,
    },
...,
    ,
}

var userfollowings = []models.UserFollowing{
    models.UserFollowing{
        ID: "",
    },
    models.UserFollowing{
        ID: "",
    },
    models.UserFollowing{
        ID: "",
    },
    models.UserFollowing{
        ID: "",
    },
}
```

Function method to load and save data to mysql db

```
for i, _ := range users {
    err = db.Debug().Model(&models.User{}).Create(&users[i]).Error
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    userfollowings[i].ID = users[i].UserId
    if i == 1 {
        userfollowings[i].Followings = append(userfollowings[i].Followings, &users[2])
        userfollowings[i].Followings = append(userfollowings[i].Followings, &users[3])
    } else if i == 2 {
        userfollowings[i].Followings = append(userfollowings[i].Followings, &users[1])
        userfollowings[i].Followings = append(userfollowings[i].Followings, &users[3])
    } else if i == 3 {
        userfollowings[i].Followings = append(userfollowings[i].Followings, &users[1])
        userfollowings[i].Followings = append(userfollowings[i].Followings, &users[2])
    } else if i == 4 {
        userfollowings[i].Followings = append(userfollowings[i].Followings, &users[3])
    }
    // The error is being generated in the following code line
    err = db.Debug().Model(&models.UserFollowing{}).Create(&userfollowings[i]).Error
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    err = db.Debug().Model(&userfollowings[i]).Related(&userfollowings[i].User, "user_id").Error
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Since yesterday, I'm unable to fix the error. I searched for similar questions and answers on the following topics:

1. How to add data to a many to many field list
2. Error 1054: Unkown column
3. Preload and relation in mysql db
   I tried the proposed solutions given on this website, but for my particular case, they didn't work.

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you define the UserFollowing in the wrong way. You need an `UserId` field in UserFollowing struct.

Read link: Click [here](https://gorm.io/docs/belongs_to.html)!

```golang
// `User` belongs to `Company`, `CompanyID` is the foreign key
type User struct {
  gorm.Model
  Name      string
  CompanyID int
  Company   Company
}

type Company struct {
  ID   int
  Name string
}
```

OR

```golang
type User struct {
  gorm.Model
  Name         string
  CompanyRefer int
  Company      Company `gorm:"foreignKey:CompanyRefer"`
  // use CompanyRefer as foreign key
}

type Company struct {
  ID   int
  Name string
}
```